# Multithreaded server using threadpool

Tags: multithreading, architecture, threadpool

I'm planing a multithreaded server (SCGI to be precise). Now, I know that the traditional approach using one thread per connection is not very scalable. I also don't want to use something fancy like libevent, as this is a hobby project and I prefer not to have lots of dependencies in my codebase.

The approach I'm thinking of is to use a threadpool and let one thread listen to the network to queue up any request coming in. The threads managed by the pool then dequeue the requests, receive the data and respond respectively.

This way, I wouldn't have the overhead of constant thread creation while still being able to serve many request in parallel.

Is there some fundamental problem in this architecture design that I'm not aware of or is this a not-ideal-but-still-ok solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. Depending on how much load this server is expected to see this might be an overkill.

One thread per connection is good enough until you start handling dozens if not hundreds requests in parallel. The advantage of one thread per connection is the simplicity, and it might not be worthwhile to give that up.

On the other hand if you are looking for something that needs to handle tons of traffic (either external like webproxy or internal like memcache) you probably should just use libevent. AFAIK all the big boys are using it or something very similar (memcache, haproxy and so on)

Finally, if you are doing this just for fun just use whatever you want :) It's possible to get good performance with all those archs.

Comment: well my approach would effectively be one-thread-per-connection, there's just a limit of active threads at a time and they don't get destroyed after they're done :). overkill is another thing I want to avoid, that's the reason why I don't want to use libevent...